# split string value in arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have to split a string-input value where-ever there is a blankspace and output the result.

eg: input:

```
I am a noob at C
```

output:

```
>>I 
>>am
>>a
>>noob
>>at
>>C
```

Code:

```
 void splitText(){
      char str[100];
      char sep[] = " \r\n";
      char *res; //if i remove this
      fgets(str,sizeof str,stdin);

      if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL) {
          printf("error");
      }
      char *p = strchr(str, '\n');
      if (p) *p = 0;
      res = strtok(str, sep); //and this
      printf("%s\n",res); //and change this to str


 }
```

Working code for anyone encountering the same problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void splitText() {
  char str[100];
  char sep[] = " \n";
  char *res;
  fgets(str,sizeof str, stdin);
  if ( fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL ) {
       printf("Error");
       break;
  }

  res = strtok(str, sep);
  while(res != NULL){
     printf("Splitted String: \"%s\"\n",res);
     res = strtok(NULL,sep);
  }

}
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed in helping me with this issue!

Comment: `char str[100] = scanf("%s",str);` , where did you read this?

Comment: `scanf()` returns an integer and you are assigning it to a char array
`scanf("%s",str)` will do your job, just remove the left part

Comment: Whenever you have an error with a particular function go read up on it. Learning what the function returns or in this case how it stores values would have probably saved you a lot of time and trouble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with

```
  char str[100] = scanf("%s",str);
```

is that you are assigning an `int` to a `char` array.

`scanf()` returns the number of items successfully scanned. The actual reading of chars into the array is done by `scanf()` itself. So you just need to call `scanf()` separately.

```
if (scanf("%s",str) != 1) { /* error */}
```

But `scanf()` is not the right tool here since you want to read a whole line. `scanf()` would stop at the first whitespace (after reading non-whitespace chars).

So when you type `"I am a noob at C"`, `scanf()` will only read the `I` and ignore the rest.

What you want is to use the [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) function to read a line:

```
  char str[100];

  if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL) {
     /* error */
  }

/* rest of the code */
```

`fgets()` would read the newline as well if there's space in the buffer. If this is undesirable, then you can remove it:

```
char *p = strchr(str, '\n');
if (p) *p = 0; //remove the trailing newline.
```

*Note:* `strtok()` is not a thread safe function. POSIX provides `strtok_r()` as a thread-safe alternative. This is something to be aware of even if it doesn't matter in this specific case.

---

Here's a self contained example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char str[100];
  char sep[] = " \n";
  char *res;

  if ( fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL ) {
     exit(1);
  }

  res = strtok(str, sep);
  while(res != NULL){
     printf("Splitted String: \"%s\"\n",res);
     res = strtok(NULL,sep);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you can ignore the `newline` by defining `char sep[] = " \r\n";` and let `strtok()` do the work.

Comment: thanks for the solution, however, if the input is "I am" the output becomes "I am" no new line :/

Comment: @WeatherVane I mentioned it as that's a relevant fact to `fgets()` which is often a source of misunderstanding about `fgets()`.

Comment: @Joel you still need to process the input string with `strtok()` and add a `newline` after every word. This answer is good because using `scanf()` will only read the first word of the sentence.

Comment: just updated the question with my current code. i cannot seem to get it to work with strtok(); It just prints out everything on the same row anyway.

Comment: @Joel You still need to loop using `strtok()`. I updated the answer with a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

That is not how `scanf()` works.

Change the code to

```
char str[100];
scanf("%s",str);
```

---

**A little note about `scanf()`**

You should check for return values, like here for `scanf()`.

```
if (scanf("%s", str) != 1)
{
    printf("scanf failed");
    exit(0);
}
```

---

You should also mention the number of `char`s to be read by `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflow.

```
scanf("%99s", str)
```

For a `char str[100]` of size `100`, one should give `99` to keep place for the null character `\0`.

---

Comment: So i cannot declare scanf immediately to str? i see.

Comment: You forget  this '&' in your scanf?

Comment: @HemantParihar I don't need the & since it's already an array.

Comment: @Haris Thanks for the solution, I have a bad habit of overthinking stuff and trying to simplify my code by making several steps into one. Unfortunately it doesn't always work the way i want it to :)

However, the output is just the first word. Any ideas on how i can get all of the results? Input: "I am" just prints out "I".

Comment: @Joel That's because scanf won't read multiple words. Use `fgets()` to read a whole line.

Comment: @Joel, check l3x's answer